# How do you put an angular project to prod?

Tags: angular, routes, production

That's my first time with Angular, and I'm trying to put my website in prod, but when I access the site, I only get index.html with its CSS and no render of .
When I try to access a route like website/home I get a Not found error ...

I've use ng build --prod and put dist content into ecowebhosting

I don't know what part of the program I need to put here so I made screen shoot of the structure:

[That's my server dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXDF.png)

[That's my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USIkZ.png)

here's my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { AccueilComponent } from './app/accueil/accueil.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './app/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

If you need more code, ask me =)

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Which webserver you are using? Try opening network tab in your browser to inspect which files can't be reached. It's not an angular issue, but your webserver configuration.

Comment: Its well documented: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: I've got this error 
Le chargement du module à l’adresse « http://keviintondo.com/polyfills-es2015.748bb1dcd6097c27f8ab.js » a été bloqué en raison d’un type MIME interdit (« text/html »).
Could it be it ?

Comment: You need to add URL Rewriting.
If your site is on php system (i.e ubuntu system) then add URL Rewriting code to .htaccess or if you are using windows server (i.e. windows 7/8/10) then use URL rewriting code to web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is URL rewriting issue.
If your website is on the PHP server then use .htaccess file with following line of text

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

If your website is on the windows system then please add following line of code to the web.config file

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
            
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```